# Unresponsive AJAX code that is supposed to load content from a different webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Tabs - Collapse content</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
     collapsible: true
   });
 });
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  $("#tabs-2").load("p2.html #content");
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#tabs-1">Alienware and Alpha</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabs-2">More About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabs-3">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p><strong>Click this tab again to close the content pane.</strong>    </p>
    <p>Alienware is an American computer hardware subsidiary of Dell, Inc. Their products are designed for gaming purposes and are best known for their science-fiction-themed designs. Alienware was founded in 1996 by Nelson Gonzalez and Alex Aguila. Alienware Alpha is a line of PC-console hybrids introduced in 2014. It contains a custom-built Nvidia GeForce GTX 860M; a Core i3, i5, or i7 Intel Processor, depending on what model is purchased, up to 8 gigabytes of RAM; and between 500 gigabytes and 2 terabytes of hard drive space..</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
  </div>
.....(other ending tags, etc.)
```

I am trying to load content from a very basic webpage which has nothing but body with a div tag #content. I want it to appear in my tab 2. But it just won't happen. Im not sure what I'm doing wrong.

p2.html:
    
    
    Ajax tab 2

```
<body>
<div id="content">

    <p>Established in 1996 by Nelson Gonzalez and Alex Aguila, Alienware assembles desktops, notebooks, workstations, and PC gaming consoles. According to employees, the name "Alienware" was chosen because of the founders' fondness for the hit television series The X-Files, with names such as Area-51, Hangar 18, and Aurora.</p>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check your p2.html path .. and check if it already has an element with  id="content" .. just try to remove #content to be .load("p2.html"); and see what you will get

Comment: Have you checked the console for any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Edit, Updated

> yes on chrome browser!

Try closing `chrome` , adjusting launcher , or launching from terminal with `/path/to/chrome --allow-file-access-from-files` flag . See [How do I make the Google Chrome flag "--allow-file-access-from-files" permanent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160245/how-do-i-make-the-google-chrome-flag-allow-file-access-from-files-permanent/192996#192996) ,  [--allow-file-access-from-files](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#allow-file-access-from-files) . See also `chrome://flags`

---

`$("#tabs-2")`not defined when `.load()` called as `<script></script>` containing `$("#tabs-2").load("p2.html #content");` within `<head></head>` element ?

Try moving `$("#tabs-2").load("p2.html #content");` within `$(function() {})`

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
      collapsible: true
    });
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $("#tabs-2").load("p2.html #content");
  });
```

Comment: tried it, but it does not display any content in the tab.

Comment: Try moving `<script></script>` containing `$(function(){})` before closing `</body>` tag

Comment: it still didn't work. I can't seem to find out what the real error is

Comment: Is jQuery defined ? Try substituting `"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"` for `"jquery-1.10.2.js"` . Can include `html` at "p2.html" at Question ? Is `js` being tried locally , or online ?

Comment: i replaced it with a link, like you stated, and also included p2 in the main question. And yes its being tried locally and i have no such specifications. I don't mind it being tried locally or online

Comment: @ceeks _"And yes its being tried locally "_  At chrome / chromium browser ?

Comment: @ceeks Tried launching chrome with `--allow-access-from-files` or `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag ?, then trying `js` ?

Answer (score 0):

Place this $("#tabs-2").load("p2.html #content") inside $(function () {}

```
$(function () {
  $("#tabs-2").load("p2.html #content")
});
```

Complete code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Collapse content</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
        $("#tabs-2").load("p2.html #content");
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Alienware and Alpha</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">More About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        Your Text!!!
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

p2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="content">
    This is p2 page!!!
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is incorrect at `$("#tabs-2").load("p2.html #content")` ?

Comment: $("#tabs-2").load("p2.html #content") doesn't work, I've tested  in IE10 & Chrome but it works with $("#tabs-2").load("p2.html")

Comment: @SudiptaMaiti _"$("#tabs-2").load("p2.html #content") doesn't work,"_ ? See http://api.jquery.com/load Issue appear to be chrome browser restricting `XMLHttpRequest` access to local filesystem

Comment: You are right, thank you - modified the code and it works as expected.